# How can I parse a string representation of an element into an actual html element?

Tags: javascript, html

For example, if I have:

`'<html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>'`

How can I parse this into an actual html element?

I've tried something like below:

```
getNodeType(element) {
  const temp = document.createElement('div');
  temp.innerHTML = element;
  if (temp.firstChild) return temp.firstChild.nodeName;
  else return null;
}
```

Which works pretty well, but I am unable to parse tags such as `<html>`, `<body>`, and `<title>` because they are unable to be contained in a div. I've also tried DOMParser but it wraps everything in html, head, and body tags, so I can't identify the actual element.

Would prefer to not use jQuery, but not completely opposed to it.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks very much!

Comment: what do you mean: How can I parse this into an actual html element?

Comment: try using `jQuery.parseHTML(data, [, context] [,keepScripts])`

Answer (score 2):

You should use DOMParser for this purpose:

```
parser = new DOMParser();
doc = parser.parseFromString('<html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>', 'text/html');
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName('p')[0])
// will print: <p>hello</p>
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: Same issue as my above comment - any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, you're saying that this solution didn't print '<p>hello</p>' to the console in your case? Or you need to distinct inner tags by some properties? I suppose you should take a look at these three methods: getElementById(), getElementsByClassName(), getElementsByTagName(). Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you had issues with `DOMParser`, it should work fine

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString('<html><body><p>hello</p></body></html>', 'text/html')
console.log(doc.firstChild.nodeName);
```

Comment: The problem with DOMParser is actually that it adds HTML and head or body tags around the element I'm targeting, so firstChild always returns html. Any ideas on how to fix this?